# How accurately can a smart phone measure pulse oximetry?

Tags: medical-device, home-medical-equipment, pulse

I want to create a medical application on Android and iOS, but I need to know what the difference is. I made a test, and know that the pulse oximeter is accurate. Is it possible for a smart phone to function as an accurate pulse oximeter? Please cite sources.